# Comment/Like actions on Facebook feed post

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to post a message to my facebook contact's feed using graph api, but what I observe is that the usual options to like those posts or to comment on them don't show up.

For example, say my application posts for FB user A on to the feed of FB user B, and I am a common contact, then I see the feed, but I don't have the options to like or comment on that feed post.

Is there any configuration to enable those options for feed posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that user B's privacy settings allow comments and likes to be made on Posts which are on their wall? 
If you are, please clarify what you're posting, are you able to like/comment on the same content if it's posted to your own wall?

Comment: Hi..thanks for replying..you are bang on target..I got the same doubt a bit later and experimented with another account of mine and confirmed that it was indeed due to privacy settings of the users involved. It just so happened that a couple of accounts for which I saw the comment/like options missing has privacy settings to not allow that and it confused me. Thanks.

Comment: No problem; I've seen plenty of bug reports come in which subsequently turned out to be due to relatively obscure privacy settings - they're often difficult to diagnose because the person reporting the bug can't supply enough information for us to replicate the bug